# Get the value of clicked element in : React

Tags: reactjs

How to get the value of a clicked element in react. 
event.currentTarget.value shows 'undefined' in react 16. Does anyone know what is the trick here ??
BTM here is the code for an instance:

```
class Test extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
    }

changeDimension(e){
    alert(e.currentTarget.value);
}

        render(){
            return(
            <div style={{height : this.state.height}} >
                        <h1 onClick={this.changeDimension.bind(this)}> Click Me</h1>
                    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` attribute is not set in:

```
<h1 onClick={this.changeDimension.bind(this)}> Click Me</h1>
```

If you need the "Click Me" text then use:

```
alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something other than "Click Me" alerted:

```
<h1 onClick={this.changeDimension.bind(this)} data-value="something other"> Click Me</h1>
```

Then:

```
alert(event.target.dataset.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

on those cases , i generally pass directly the value as a parameter on the function , especially if i have multiple buttons generated by a loop , for example :

```
{this.state.dimensions.map(dimension => <h1 onClick={() => this.changeDimension(dimension)}>{dimension.value}</h1>)}
```